# Figures in (3*2) pattern with labels in a particular manner

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I need figures along with the labels in the following manner

```
(a)   (d)

(b)   (e)

(c)   (f)
```

How to achieve this? Normally the figures are labelled from left to right and then vertically down and so on. But I want them in the format shown above.
Can it be done? If yes, how?

Comment: Please tell us which package(s) you employ to create the subfigures.

Comment: subfigure package and resizebox command

Comment: The `subfigure` package is deprecated. Don't use it. Instead, use either the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you create two side-by-side `minipage` environments, each containing three subfigures.  I would *not* use `\resizebox`.

The following proposed solution employs the `subcaption` package and its `subfigure` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{a.pdf}
\caption{A}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{b.pdf}
\caption{B}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{c.pdf}
\caption{C}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{\fill} % maximize the horizontal separation
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{d.pdf}
\caption{D}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{e.pdf}
\caption{E}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{f.pdf}
\caption{F}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}

\caption{Overall figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I hve a doubt. Instead of (a)-(f), I am getting separate figure numbers for each subfigure, which i don't want. I want the figures exactly as you have shown in the screenshot. But instead, I am getting different figure numbers for each subfigure

Comment: @ShiS - Did you (a) load the `subcaption` package and (b) embed the two `minipage` environments in a `figure` environment? Do please tell which LaTeX document class you employ.

Comment: Thesis.cls', based on 'ECSthesis.cls', by Steve R. Gun

Comment: Got it. Subcaption package was clashing with graphicx. Understood now